# Animation glitch with canvas and angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas

I just want to make a night sky in canvas and use it in an angular partial but about half of the stars flash in and out of existence crazily. Maybe I'm nuts but I can't find why in the code. Here's the partial:

```
<div  class="container-fluid" ng-controller="View1Ctrl as v1c">     
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

And here's the javascript:

```
angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/view1', {
templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
controller: 'View1Ctrl'
});
}])

.controller('View1Ctrl', [function() {
this.source = 'view1/startest.png';
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    var width = screen.width;
    var height= screen.height;
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    var stars = [];
    var colors = ['#ffffff', '#ffd9cc', '#b3ecff'];

    for (i = 0; i < 600; i++) {
      stars.push({
        locx: Math.floor(Math.random() * width-10) + 1,
        locy: Math.floor(Math.random() * height - 10) + 1,
        radius: Math.random(),
        color: colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)]
      });
    };

    function twinkle() {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
      for (i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
        var star = stars[i];
        ctx.fillStyle = star.color;
        var changeIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(star.locx, star.locy, star.radius , 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
      };
    };

    function twinkleLoop() {
      window.setTimeout(twinkleLoop, 20);
        twinkle();
    };

    twinkleLoop();
 });
}]);
```

Any help very welcome! They're placed in an animation function so that eventually I can get them to animate, but on my own terms, so that has to stay or at least only get modified and not removed.

Comment: Use `resquestAnimationFrame` instead of `setTimeout` and it will fix your flicker. Very similar to setTimeout apart from providing the time, that is done by the browser to ensure smooth and flicker free animation.

Comment: interesting. I'll give it a shot, but I should have mentioned I tried the same javascript in a small, non-angular test html file and it worked fine. regardless I'll try anything that is suggested

Comment: Canvas size will effect flickering. 20ms is out of sync with 1/60th display refresh When rendering with setTimeout or its uglier sibling setInterval the browser does not know when you are done with your rendering, So on some frames it will present the canvas just after you clear it, then next frame after drawing some stars, requestAnimationFrame ensures that the browser will not present the canvas until your function has returned. It also keeps time with the screen refresh so that you do not get shearing. As then name sugests it is there for Animations (and not just canvas animation)

Comment: ooooooh! fantastic. can't wait to try it. thanks!

Comment: that was the solution. thanks!